# Best way to communicate between Android app and external database

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, architecture

I am starting an Android app and i will need to have a external database, maybe MySQL.

What is the best way to link my app at my database? Should i have a web application with controllers to acess at database or should i create webservices to make connection beetween my app and my server?

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a webservice that will have an API in order to get instructions from Android and native access to your Db.

Comment: Ok, i understand you but i have any questions. I will create many webservices and need to deploy it on a local to can access from my android app. Can i have it on a local server (my desktop) or i need to pay some server on internet to deploy my webservices? thanks

Comment: You can have it locally if you want.